# Creating an array with the index of rows that have been checked off

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table set up with a checkbox in each row and I am trying to create an array with the index of the rows that have been checked off.

I have tried the following code but it returns "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Can anyone help me out?

```
function clearSelected(){

var checked = $('input:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").index()
.map(function(){
    return this.index;
}).get().join();

}
```

Comment: `.index()` returns a number, `.map()` has to be applied to an array.

Comment: Could you post the html (a jsfiddle/stack snippet would be really helpful)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.index()` inside the `map()` function:

```
var checked = $('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').map(function() {
    return $(this).index();
}).get();
```

Comment: Or use [`this.rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex). But of course you're correct that not having `.index()` in the chain before `.map()` is key, and `.closest()` instead of `.parents()` is sensible.